# Android synchronous connection to REST/JSON - Volley, VolleyPlus or Retrofit?

Tags: json, rest, android-volley, synchronous, retrofit

I developed all my app using Volley with different classes (POJO, Parser, JSON request) for the different sections of the navigation drawer (7 in total) however after getting everything up and running I realised it needs to use synchronous/blocking requests which volley doesn't usually do. All Volley requests are asynchronous which means sometimes I click a button or a drawer item and it doesn't show any results because the asynchronous request didn't finish.

I did some research and found a couple of options:

- Volley's own RequestFuture() method
- VolleyPlus https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus
- Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/

I'm having a hard time to find tutorials or examples on the first 2 options to send GET/POST requests with parameters (X-Auth-Token, Content-Type, Accept application/json, etc) and moving to Retrofit means I'd have to throw away all the code I've already written and restart from scratch.

What is your recommendation? Any Volley/VolleyPlus examples or tutorials for this use case? Would the move to Retrofit be worth the re-work?

UPDATE:

I started playing with Retrofit and replacing some of my Volley calls. It's perfect! It does exactly what I wanted with even less code than Volley. So far I'm not doing the automatic parsing, just getting the raw HTTP response in JSON format and sending to the previous parser classes I had but eventually I'll get them replaced as well when I get my head around the POJOs and GSON. I had to disable strict mode on the main activity for the synchronous calls and add a try/catch to deal with some errors. Here's the Retrofit code on one of the methods:

```
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(neutronURL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));
    builder.setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
            request.addHeader("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
        }
    });
    RestAdapter adapter = builder.build();
    SecurityAPI api = adapter.create(SecurityAPI.class);
    if (security == null){
        pDialog.setMessage("Contacting Server...");
        pDialog.show();
    }

    try {
        Response result = api.getSecSync();
        security = getRawJSON(result);
    } catch (RetrofitError e) {
        Log.d("Retrofit Error", e.toString());
        if (e.toString().contains("Unauthorized")){
            tokenExpiredAlert();
        }
        if (offline==0 && e.toString().contains("Unable to resolve host")){
            offlineAlert();
        }
    }
```

And the interface it calls:

```
public interface SecurityAPI {
@Headers({
        "Accept: application/json",
        "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"
})
@GET("/v2.0/security-groups")
//void getSecurityContent(Callback<Response> callback);
Response getSecSync();
```

}

UPDATE2:

About VolleyPlus, how would I use it with this code? I tried but didn't get it to work, got several errors about abstract classes:

```
     JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, novaURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("Nova on Response", response.toString());
                    setNovaJSON(response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d("Nova on Error", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    setNovaJSON(error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("X-Auth-Token", authToken);
            params.put("Accept", "application/json");
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }

    };


    queue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue();
    //VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(getRequest);
    queue.add(getRequest);
```

Comment: Recently i made a WebAPI Spotify Rest client using Volley https://github.com/SiegenthalerSolutions/spotify-web-api-android maybe it could help you! Cheers.

Comment: You should never do synchronous or wait for a request on the UI thread (Main Thread).

Comment: It must be synchronous, no other way around it. When I click a section of the navigation drawer I need the data to be displayed on the fragment. Using the asynchronous volley request the fragment just shows empty and I need to click again to get the data.

Comment: IF the user has a slow connection it will cause an ANR since you're doing a network operation in the main thread (Unless you're not, but a click happends in the main thread if not mistaken), maybe you should rethink on how to do it asynchronous. Have you though using Retrofit + Robospice?

Comment: My app basically loads a navigation drawer and each section of the drawer loads a fragment. Each fragment I have separate auxiliary classes (POJO, Volley JSON Request, JSON Parser and RecyclerView) and none of them are on the main thread. Some times the recycler view on the fragment still loads empty or I click an item and it shows the values from the previous item, if I click a 2nd time I get the right data. Those problems wouldn't happen with synchronous requests. My app is supposed to be used via wireless connecting to an internal server, no slow internet.

Comment: @GITcommitEd I would parse out your second question and create a new question on SO. Don't try to group question together. 1) Its harder to answer sometimes 2) Other people might have the same issue. Glad to see Retrofit is working nicely for you though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not completely answer your question but merely I'll share my opinion.

As a lead Android dev for a startup, I started with Volley (Towards the end of 2013) and ran into issues. I switched over to Retrofit within a weeks time.

The Synchronouss vs Asynchronous comes in the form of callbacks. If a callback is present Retrofit knows to run it asynchronously, otherwise it waits to return the value.

Comment: Thanks, the more I read the more it looks like Retrofit would do everything I want in a much easier way. The Volley documentation sucks and it's hard to find information about simple things like sync vs async. However I really wanted to try to stick with volley as I'd have to re-code 30+ classes, if I could find a way to work properly with sync requests and progress bars it would save me lots of time

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use [VolleyPlus](https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus) for synchronous request, its very simple.

`Volley` is replace by `VolleyTickle`

`RequestQueue` is replaced by `RequestTickle`

`request.start()` gives `NetworkResponse` .

```
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.POST, apiUrl, null, null);

    RequestTickle mRequestTickle = VolleyTickle.newRequestTickle(getApplicationContext());
    mRequestTickle.addRequest(request);
    NetworkResponse response = mRequestTickle.start();
    if(response.StatusCode = 200){
       String data = VolleyTickle.parseResponse(response);
    }
```

Comment: See UPDATE2 above, I couldn't get it to work with JSON Requests

Comment: I cant figure what issue you are getting with JsonObjectRequest. I tried your code and it work. If you can post the errors, i would be happy to help. Here is an example which works https://github.com/DWorkS/VolleyPlus/blob/master/sample/src/com/volley/demo/ExampleJsonRequest.java

Comment: This is what i get: Error:(118, 46) error: <anonymous com.stackerz.app.Instances.NovaJSON$2> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onErrorResponse(VolleyError) in ErrorListener
Error:(119, 21) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(126, 40) error: getHeaders() in <anonymous com.stackerz.app.Instances.NovaJSON$3> cannot override getHeaders() in Request
overridden method does not throw AuthFailureError

Comment: Have you tried the example i have pointed. Does these errors come in that example also? In the code you have shared i dont see any NovaJSON class. Are these runtime errors or compile errors? I am not able to help much with this info as i tried with the same code and it simply works. May be there are other things which i'm missing. I would really appreciate if you can create a sample project which doesnt work and i will be more than happy to look into the issue.

Comment: @GITcommitEd VolleyPlus works fine with me, just make sure to organize import and remove the old dependency ('com.android.volley:volley:x.y.z').

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple using Retrofit to make synchronous call:

```
public interface TaskService {
    @GET("/tasks")
    List<Task> getTasks();
}

[..]

List<Task> tasks = getTasks();
```

and asynchronous:

```
@GET("/tasks")
void getTasks(Callback<List<Task>> callback);

[..]

getTasks(new Callback<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Task> tasks, Response response) {
        }
    };
```

);

More at source:
https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few similarly named items in the two that share different namespaces.I had a similar issue and had to change some of the below listed once I removed volley and replaced it with volleyplus to accomodate for multiple file uploads without having to use HttpEntity and Multipart Entity:

- **com.android.volley.VolleyError** to **com.android.volley.error.VolleyError**
- **com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest** to **com.android.volley.request.JsonObjectRequest**
- **com.android.volley.AuthFailureError** to **com.android.volley.error.AuthFailureError**